# How do I extend the lifetime of a temporary in a ranged for expression?

Tags: c++, reference, c++14, ranged-loops

I'm getting dangling references while using a ranged-for loop. Consider the following C++14 expression (full example program below):

```
    for(auto& wheel: Bike().wheels_reference())
        wheel.inflate();
```

It's output is:

```
 Wheel()
 Wheel()
 Bike()
~Bike() with 0 inflated wheels.
~Wheel()
~Wheel()
 Wheel::inflate()
 Wheel::inflate()
```

Obviously something is going very wrong. Wheels are accessed beyond their lifetime and the result is 0, not the expected 2.

An easy fix is to introduce a variable for `Bike` in `main`. However, I do not control the code in `main` or `Wheel`. I can only change the struct `Bike`.

Is there any way to fix this example by only changing `Bike`?

A successful solution solution will either fail at compile time, or count 2 inflated tires and not touch any objects beyond their lifetimes.

## Appendix: compile ready source

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct Wheel
{
    Wheel() { cout << " Wheel()" << endl; }
    ~Wheel() { cout << "~Wheel()" << endl; }
    void inflate() { inflated = true; cout << " Wheel::inflate()" << endl; }
    bool inflated = false;
};

struct Bike
{
    Bike() { cout << " Bike()" << endl; }
    ~Bike() {
        cout << "~Bike() with " << std::count_if(wheels.begin(),    wheels.end(),
            [](auto& w) { return w.inflated; }) << " inflated wheels." << endl;
    }
    std::array<Wheel, 2>& wheels_reference() { return wheels; }
    std::array<Wheel, 2> wheels{Wheel(), Wheel()};
};

int main()
{
    for(auto& wheel: Bike().wheels_reference())
        wheel.inflate();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If only in `Bike`, than function `reference` should return array by value, not by reference, but I think, it's not what you want.

Comment: @ForEveR but `auto&` couldn't bind to that.

Comment: @ForEveR: While it solves the use-after destroy, it does not satisfy my conditions for a solution. The printed value will be 0, not 2.

Comment: @TartanLlama but binds in both gcc/clang.

Comment: @ForEveR Huh, I guess by brain-compiler is broken.

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: Change the loop to `for(auto& wheel: Bike().wheels)` and it's fine.

Comment: @erip: You must have copied it in between two edits where I introduced a small bug. Current code compiles for me with: `clang++ -std=c++14 ./code.cpp -o ./code`. Please try again.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Thanks! That is an interesting solution, but I'm not sure if it is usable in my context, since I can not change `main`.

Comment: @Remco Make `Bike()` a function returning a reference to a singleton then :) I think you have come across a weakness in the standard relating to lifetime extension of temporary objects.

Comment: I disagree that it's duplicate actually, question is not about rules, but about how handle this situation.

Comment: Thanks @ForEveR. I'm indeed aware of what is going on and asking for a workaround.

Comment: Here's a workaround: stop doing this: `Bike().wheels_reference()`. Stop accessing the members of a temporary.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Sounds good. How do I turn it into compile time errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the rvalue overload of `wheels_reference`.

```
std::array<Wheel, 2>& wheels_reference() & { return wheels; }
std::array<Wheel, 2>& wheels_reference() && = delete;
```

That way you won't return a reference to a member of a temporary.

Your example usage of the `Bike` class

```
for(auto& wheel: Bike().wheels_reference())
    wheel.inflate();
```

Will then refuse to compile with (clang 3.4 output):

```
test.cpp:31:29: error: call to deleted member function 'wheels_reference'
    for(auto& wheel: Bike().wheels_reference())
                     ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:24:27: note: candidate function has been explicitly deleted
    std::array<Wheel, 2>& wheels_reference() && = delete;
                          ^
test.cpp:23:27: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Bike' to 'Bike' for object argument
    std::array<Wheel, 2>& wheels_reference() & { return wheels; }
```

If the lifetime of the temporary is manually extended things work.

```
Bike&& bike = Bike();
for(auto& wheel: bike.wheels_reference())
    wheel.inflate();
```

Comment: I am puzzled about the non exiting function and "std::array<Wheel, 2>& wheels_reference() && = delete;"

Comment: @DieterLücking check this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions

Comment: Why do you need to delete `&&` overloading? You can just define single `&` overloading.

Comment: @Orient you are right, but the error messages I get when only providing the lvalue-ref overload is not as good: clang gives the most unhelpful `error: cannot initialize object parameter of type 'Bike' with an expression of type 'Bike'` while g++5 tells me that `error: passing ‘Bike’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers`. Explicitly deleting an overload is much clearer.

Comment: @jepio Right you are.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to stop getting members of a type through a member function call on temporary.

If `wheels_reference` were a non-member function, you could simply declare it like this:

```
wheels_reference(Bike &bike);
```

Since a non-const lvalue parameter cannot be attached to a temporary, you would be unable to call `wheels_reference(Bike())`. Since `wheels_reference` is a member function, you'll just have to use the member function syntax for saying the same thing:

```
std::array<Wheel, 2>& wheels_reference() & //<--
{ return wheels; }
```

If the user now tries to call `Bike().wheels_reference()`, the compiler will complain.

Comment: Perfect! Essentially the same as @jeplo's solution. The analogy with non-member functions is insightful.

Answer (score 1):

The following horrible contraption seems to satisfy all the conditions:

```
#include <memory>

struct Bike
{
    // Bike() { cout << " FakeBike()" << endl; }
    // ~Bike() { cout << "~FakeBike()" << endl; }
    struct RealBike;
    struct Wrap {
        std::shared_ptr<RealBike> parent;
        auto begin() { return parent->wheels.begin(); }
        auto end() { return parent->wheels.end(); }
    };
    struct RealBike {
        RealBike() { cout << " Bike()" << endl; }
        ~RealBike() {
            cout << "~Bike() with " << std::count_if(wheels.begin(),    wheels.end(),
                [](auto& w) { return w.inflated; }) << " inflated wheels." << endl;
        }
        std::array<Wheel, 2> wheels;
    };
    std::shared_ptr<RealBike> real = std::make_shared<RealBike>();
    Wrap wheels_reference() { return Wrap{real}; }
};
```

What I don't like is that it requires wrapping all the API of `std::array<Wheel, 2>` in `Wrap`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add a couple of cv-ref-qualified overloadings of `wheels_reference` member function:

```
std::array<Wheel, 2>& wheels_reference() & { return wheels; }

std::array<Wheel, 2> const & wheels_reference() const & { return wheels; }

std::array<Wheel, 2> wheels_reference() && { return std::move(wheels); }

std::array<Wheel, 2> wheels_reference() const && { return wheels; }
```

Note, if object is temporary (`&&` case), then you should return a value (copy-constructed from data member or even better move-constructed from it), nor reference.

Having all four overloadings you cover all the use-cases possible.